# Post in master triggers Post in detail

Tags: delphi, lazarus, freepascal

Is it expected behaviour that TSQLQuery qryMaster.Post triggers Post in qryDetail?

EDIT: This is for Lazarus, but I'm also interested how it is handled in Delphi.

I have a settings dialog where fields in Master are edited and posted first, and if Detail is modified too it is also posted. I try to do this manually as you see below. But the detail query never gets posted manually since Master triggered Detail's AfterPost and Detail.Modified is no longer true. How to deal with this:

```
function TfrmDataset.SaveDataset: Boolean;
begin
  Result:=False;
  try
    DM.qryDataset.Post;
    DM.qryDataset.ApplyUpdates;

    if DM.qryLinks.Modified then
    begin
      DM.qryLinks.FieldByName('dataset_id').AsInteger:=
      DM.qryDataset.FieldByName('dataset_id').AsInteger;

      DM.qryLinks.Post;
      DM.qryLinks.ApplyUpdates;
    end;
    DM.TX.CommitRetaining;
    Result:=True;
  except
    DM.TX.RollbackRetaining;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Are you asking about the TSQLQuery which is part of Delphi's DBExpress, or the TSQLQuery which comes with Lazarus?  Afaik, they just have the same name, not the same implementation.

Comment: This is for Lazarus.